# How to prove that this relation R is transitive?

Tags: equivalence-relations

Consider the following relation R on the set $W =\{0,1\}^{16}.$ For every two sequences $a = (a_1, \ldots,a_{16})$ and $b = (b_1,\ldots,b_{16})$ from $W$, we have
$R(a,b)$ if and only if $b = (a_k,\ldots ,a_{16},a_1, \ldots,a_{k−1})$ for some $k \in \{1, \ldots,16\}$. (a) Prove that R is an equivalence relation.

This is what I have done so far:

Let $aRb$ such that there exists $a_k \in \{1,...,16\}, b =\{b_1,...,b_{16}\} = \{a_k,\ldots,a_{16},a_1,\ldots,a_{k-1}\}$

Let $bRc$ such that $k' \in \{1,...,16\}, c = \{c_1,\ldots,c_{16}\} = \{b_{k'},\ldots,b_{16},b_1,...b_{k'-1}\}$

Now i'm not sure how to write $c$ in terms of the sequence a to prove that $aRc$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: How did you prove reflexivity and symmetry?

Comment: For reflexivity I showed that aRa when k = 1. For symmetry, I showed that aRb for some k then for some m ∈ {1,...,16} a = (bm,...,b16,b1,...,bm-1} hence bRa. @DougM

Comment: try a (smaller) example first (replace all $b_k$ in the relation $bRc$ with the respective $a_k$ in the relation $aRb$

Comment: Hint: consider the map (circular permutation) $\sigma:(x_1,\dots,x_{16})\mapsto(x_2,x_3,\dots,x_{16},x_1)$ and its [iterates $\sigma^k$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function) (which depend only on $k\bmod{16}$). This will simplify your notations.

Comment: @AnneBauval im not sure how to express it as a function of k

Comment: @AnneBauval =(1,…,16) =(,…,16,1,…,−1) a = (bm,...,b16,b1,...,bm-1}.  This shows that a1 = bm, a16 = bm-1 , ak-1 = b16 and ak = b1

Comment: Ok thank you for your patience. Now, my hint above might help for transitivity.

Answer (score 1):

By definition $$aR b\iff \exists k\in[\![1,16]\!]\text{ such that }b=(a_k,\ldots,a_{16},a_1,\ldots,a_{k-1})$$ which means that $b$ is obtained from $a$ by shifting the first $k-1$ elements to the right. Then  we have
\begin{align*}
b_j&=a_{(j+k-1)\ mod\ 16},\qquad \forall j\in[\![1,16]\!]\setminus\{\ 17-k\} \\
b_{17-k}&=a_{16}
\end{align*}
So to prove transitivity, let $a,b,c\in W$ such that $aR b$ and $bR c$, then  $\exists k,s\in[\![1,16]\!]$ such that
$$b_j=a_{(j+k-1)\ mod\ 16}\quad \text{and}\quad c_j=b_{(j+s-1)\ mod\ 16},\quad\forall j\in[\![1,16]\!]\setminus\{\ 17-k,17-s\}.$$ To prove $aRc$ we must write each $c_j$ in terms of coordinates of $a$ as the definition. We just replace in the two previous relations we obtain:
\begin{align*}
c_j&=b_{\color{blue}{\textrm{(j+s-1) $mod$ 16}}}\\
&=a_{\big(\color{blue}{\textrm{(j+s-1) $mod$ 16}}+k-1\big)mod\ 16}\\
&=a_{(j+s-1+k-1)mod\ 16}\\
&=a_{(j+m-1)mod\ 16}
\end{align*}
where $m:=(k+s-1)\mod 16$. In this way we get
$c=(c_1,\ldots,c_{16})=(a_m,\ldots,a_{16},a_1,\ldots,a_{m-1})$, i.e, $aRc$ as desired. $ \qquad \qquad \square $
For example, we have
$$c_1=a_{(1+m-1)\ mod\ 16}=a_{m\ mod\ 16}=a_m$$
$$c_{16}=a_{(16+m-1)\ mod\ 16}=a_{(m+15)\ mod\ 16}=a_{(m-1)\ mod\ 16}=a_{m-1}$$
Note we do the reduction modulo $16$ in indexation to  ensure indexing stays in the interval  $[\![1,16]\!]$.